# Dnn Instalation error in Windows 8.1

Tags: dotnetnuke, windows-8.1, dotnetnuke-7, iis-8.5

I'm trying install dotnetnuke but when i do Browse "default.aspx" file from iis, this error has been Occurs:

DNN Error
Connection To The Database Failed

dnn version: 7.02
iis version: 8.5
os: windows 8.1
sql server: Sql2012

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your connection string is in the web.config and is correctly pointing to your database. Also make sure the sql server user login used in the connection string works, if you are not using integrated security.

Hope this helps.
Chuck

Comment: i use dnn defualt connection string that set in dnn web.config in .zip file

Answer (score 0):

You really should install DNN 7.3.2, the latest release, but if you must 7.2.0 should work fine too.

You are missing a database connection, so the question is, what SQL server are you using?

Here's a tutorial on setting up DNN in a development environment.
http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/1